# can't install nordvpn on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

today I removed nordvpn and tried to install it again, I followed all steps that mentioned in the official website and still can't get it work.

```
sudo apt install ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb

sudo apt update

sudo apt install nordvpn

E: Package 'nordvpn' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: ```sudo dpkg -i ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb``` . BTW, StackOverflow is dedicated to software development and you question is off-topic here.  [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) would be better place to ask such question.

Comment: I tried that too, doesn't work

Comment: your question will be deleted soon as off-topic. I you want to get any kind of answer then please include any relevant information into the question